# "Double XP" vs "Double Weapon XP" in MW3

Tags: call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3

What's the difference between "Double XP" vs "Double Weapon XP" in Call of Duty Modern Warfare 3?

Which is the better choice?

Comment: I chose "Double Weapon XP", but now I'm thinking I should have chosen "Double XP"... lol

Comment: duble weapon xp because eventually you'll get to level 80

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Double XP will cause your "Player Level" (Your actual level) to progress at twice the normal rate, which will cause you to unlock new guns and perks at twice the normal rate (while it's active)

Double Weapon XP will cause your "Weapon Levels" (the level noted individually for every weapon) to progress at twice the normal rate, which will cause you to unlock new attachments for that specific gun at twice the normal rate (while it's active).

Double XP will not cause your guns to level up faster, and Double Weapon XP will not cause you to level up faster.

Both can be active at the same time however, causing both you and your guns to level up twice as quickly.

Comment: I believe that weapon XP also controls Camo unlocks, in addition to weapon proficiency/perks (like Kick and Flinch reduction, etc) and attachments.

Comment: @agent86 your right. Weapon XP goes for everything related to the weapon(s).

Answer (score 6):

Sorry to answer my own question... but...

After searching more, it sounds like you can unlock things specific to weapons such as attachments, etc with "Double Weapon XP", but it doesn't help your overall XP. Similarly "Double XP" helps your overall XP, but not weapon-specific XP.

I found the answer here:
http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/995751-call-of-duty-modern-warfare-3/60609664

Comment: Don't worry about answering your own question, that is fine.  But this is still kind of ambiguous.  Are you saying that the two are completely different, one effects the player's XP, and one effects the weapon's?  Or does Double XP do both?

Comment: Mr Smooth clarified that they don't affect each other.

Answer (score 3):

Weapon xp inadvertently affects your regular xp because as your guns level up faster you reach mastery level (a challenge) which gives you 10,000xp....which helps level you up.

Answer (score 2):

Double XP will cause you to level up faster, unlocking new weapons faster etc.

Double Weapon XP will only cause you to get closer to unlocking emblems or callsigns.

Answer (score 2):

Double xp makes you rank up faster example: reaching commander faster

Double weapon xp makes your guns rank up faster example:unlocking attachments,proifencies,camo,reticle faster